# 3.5mm, 4 conductor, in-line, plug

Tags: audio, soldering, wire, speakers, plug

I am struggling to find pictures of the `plug` I bought to figure out where to connect speaker wire to. It is a `TRRS 3.5mm plug` that I am connecting to `4-pole speaker wires`. On the side which will recieve the speaker wires, what locations do I solder ground/microphone/left/right to? Is the longest chrome piece (facing down in the picture) the ground?
[image]

Comment: You did not say that this a phone connector, there are a lot of different standards. Only for the phones it is either CTIA or ORTF, information can be easily googled on this topic.

Comment: wait...i am trying to take 4 pole audio output from a bluetooth module and convert it to 3.5mm to input into a speaker amplifier...do i have the right plug for this? or is this to plug in headphones to an iphone or something? I am trying to plug it into a speaker amplifier

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct diagram, I will solder now:

[image]

Comment: although there are two different scenarios for ground/microphone in this i am realizing...

Comment: The TRRS jack is usually used for the output, unless your speaker has a microphone built in that you want to return the signal to the Bluetooth, and I've never seen that in a wired speaker, you only need the TRS style plug. You can just short the ring nearest the sleeve to the sleeve to achieve the same thing.